# Multiply a column with each values of an array

Tags: postgresql

How to multiply a column value with each element present in the array without using loop?

I have tried using the for each loop which iterates over the loop and multiplying each element with the column value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
public.test_p_offer_type_simulation1(offers numeric[])
RETURNS TABLE(sku character varying, cannibalisationrevenue double 
precision, cannibalisationmargin double precision)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$ declare a numeric []:= offers;
i numeric;
begin
foreach i in array a loop return QUERY 
  select
    base.sku,
    i * base.similar_sku,
  .................
```

Suppose I have a column name 'baseline', and have an array [1,2,3], I want to multiply a baseline column value where its id =1 with each element of the array.

Example:::

```
 id  | baseline 
 ----+----------
  1  | 3
```

suppose I have an array with values [2,3,4]; I want to multiply baseline= 3 with (3 *2) , (3*3), (3*4). and return 3 rows after multiplication with values 6, 9, 12.

The output should be:

```
  id | result| number
 ----+-------+---------
  1      6       2
  1      9       3
  1     12       4
```

Comment: Give a clear example of your orginal data and output data

Comment: @Shawn.X I have updated the question with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, according to your description, just use `unnest` function, the example SQL as below:

```
with tmp_table as (
select 1 as id, 3 as baseline, '{2,3,4}'::int[] as arr
)
select id,baseline*unnest(arr) as result,unnest(arr) as number from tmp_table;
 id | result | number 
----+--------+--------
  1 |      6 |      2
  1 |      9 |      3
  1 |     12 |      4
(3 rows)
```

You can just replace the CTE `table_tmp` above to your real table name.

Comment: with tmp_table as (
select 1 as id, 1 as baseline, '{2,3,4}'::int[] as arr from table_name where id = 1
)
select id,baseline,baseline*unnest(tmp_table.arr) as result from tmp_table ;

Comment: no man, I just rewritten the query with a working one as inside the CTE of your query you had forgotten to mention the from clause . BTW thanks a lot man!!

Comment: @RohanKumar you're welcome. The SQL above is just a simple example, you can improve it to meet your needs. And if it's convenient for you, accept my answer please. Thanks! :D

Comment: yeah I did accept, I was wondering how to get the element as well against which it was multiplied with. For example in  [2,3,4] I want to print 2, 3, 4 as well, i.e. the number against which baseline was multiplied with

Comment: @RohanKumar You mean you want to add a column to display the original array?

Comment: no, I want the array element against which baseline was multiplied against. for example according to the given data, baseline = 1, array = [2,3,4]; the output should be :: baseline*2, 2 and baseline*3, 3  and baseline*4,4 . This will be the rows

Comment: Can you give a complete example above of what you want to get, so I can write a new SQL for you to solve your problem. @RohanKumar

Comment: yeah I have edited the question with the sample data and the required output. Please look into it.

Comment: @RohanKumar OK, I have updated my answer, just use `unnest` twice, check again.

Comment: great!! Thanks again!! Should have applied my common sense :)

Comment: @RohanKumar Good Luck :D